# Laravel Process can't find Node

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am developing a Laravel (8.83.24) app and testing with Laravel's built in server "php artisan serve". I am using Process and am trying to debug a memory allocation error which has lead me to here:

```
$process = new Process(['node', '-v']);
$process->run();
print_r($process);
```

That leads me to a line in the output:

```
[command] => cmd /V:ON /E:ON /D /C (node -v) 1>"C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Temp\sf_proc_01.out" 2>"C:\Users\mat\AppData\Local\Temp\sf_proc_01.err"
```

and sf_proc_01.err contains:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Clearly node can't be found. I am on Windows 10. Node is set in my in System and User PATH. Running "node -v" from cmd.exe works and returns the version number. So Laravel's server doesn't seem to be able to find node. However, I can't check the path as running this:

```
$process = new Process(['echo', '%PATH%']);
$process->run();
print_r($process);
```

Just leads to an output of

```
"%PATH%"
```

How can I make Node findable by Laravel / Process?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The path set in your user doesn't always translate to the path in the command line or the web server user. Try using the full path to node instead.

Comment: Thanks @aynber. This is deep within a package, so any hard-coded solution doesn't work long term but your response did at least allow me to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this by setting the path for node in my Laravel .env file:

```
NODE_PATH='C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs\node.exe'
NPM_PATH='D:\Work\Project\node_modules'
```